# Convert Character to Int in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, int, character, swift-playground, swift2

I just want to convert a **character** into an **Int**.

This should be simple. But I haven't found the previous answers helpful. There is always some error. Perhaps it is because I'm trying it in Swift 2.0.

```
for i in (unsolved.characters) {
  fileLines += String(i).toInt()
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is related to old and unsupported version of a Swift compiler

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In Swift 2.0, `toInt()`, etc., have been replaced with initializers. (In this case, `Int(someString)`.)

Because not all strings can be converted to ints, this initializer is *failable*,  which means it returns an *optional int* (`Int?`) instead of just an `Int`. The best thing to do is unwrap this optional using `if let`.

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but this code works in Swift 2, and accomplishes what I think you're trying to do:

```
let unsolved = "123abc"

var fileLines = [Int]()

for i in unsolved.characters {
    let someString = String(i)
    if let someInt = Int(someString) {
        fileLines += [someInt]
    }
    print(i)
}
```

Or, for a Swiftier solution:

```
let unsolved = "123abc"

let fileLines = unsolved.characters.filter({ Int(String($0)) != nil }).map({ Int(String($0))! })

// fileLines = [1, 2, 3]
```

You can shorten this more with `flatMap`:

```
let fileLines = unsolved.characters.flatMap { Int(String($0)) }
```

`flatMap` returns "an `Array` containing the non-nil results of mapping `transform` over `self`"… so when `Int(String($0))` is `nil`, the result is discarded.

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything is working, except fileLines is an Array of Ints for me. var fileLines: [Int] = [] (it says that fileLines cannot use +=)

Comment: You can use the append method, or do `fileLines += [someInt]`

Answer (score 9):

This is a bit of improvisational trick I came up with. Since it can be tricky to convert `Character` to `Int`, but you can easily convert `String` to `Int`
do this :

```
fileLines = Int(String(i))!
```

of course this is not very well optimized but for cases like yours it can do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Actually.  A simpler way is to convert String to Int in Swift 2.o is:

```
let chars = Int(chars)
```

Not sure if this is what you're trying for...But you can easily apply this to your loop, of course.

Comment: This seems way easier.

Comment: `chars` cannot be both the new created constant and the parameter of `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 solutions

To convert a `Character` to a `String`:

```
let digit = Int(String("1"))! 
//Don't force unwrap this if you're not 100% sure your character is a digit
```

Solution to OPs problem:

```
let fileLines = unsolved.compactMap{ Int(String($0) }
// fileLines = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the latest Swift versions (at least in Swift 5) you don't need to do additional conversion to `String`.

`Character` has property `wholeNumberValue` which tries to convert a character to `Int` and returns `nil` if the character does not represent and integer.

```swift
let char: Character = "5"
if let intValue = char.wholeNumberValue {
    print("Value is \(intValue)")
} else {
    print("Not an integer")
}
```